# How do I install google play services?

Tags: android, android-service, google-play, google-play-services

I am extremely sorry if this question dosen't meant to be asked here . But Today  I bought HTC  ONE SU model from CHINA. I installed many apps including Google Plus wit HTC market but when I open it , it says " Google play services need to be installed".

I know there is no google apps in this handset. How can I install google play services? Also how can I install English(US) rather than what I have English(CHINA) now ?
Step by step intructions will be helpful . I tried to serach on internet but coudlnt find satisfactory answer. Any link will also help me.

Thanks a lot

Comment: As you feared, this question is off topic here, you should try android.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Jave Thanks Moderator please move this to  android.stackexchange.com .No I am not afraid at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK every android device from china doesn't come with gapps installed
so you need to unlock bootloader,  root your phone and install gapps manually from recovery

follow this link http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2000540 it may help you :)

EDIT:

i just found the complete instruction and it should help you http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=41847639&postcount=496

Answer (score 0):

Open the following link: 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.maps&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5nb29nbGUuYW5kcm9pZC5hcHBzLm1hcHMiXQ

and install this "map" application.

Google play services lib is included inside this app.

Comment: I have already downloaded. But still services not installed:( not even my contacts are synced

Comment: Give me your  email id ,i will send you sample map application with google play service lib.

Comment: only after testing sample map application on your phone i can say further about the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you.

http://www.androidguys.com/2013/04/11/how-to-install-google-play-store-v4-0/

It is however strange that your phone does not have google play

Comment: I tried this aready . It didnt work for me. Yes if you buy mobile or tablet in china . You will not get google services installed in that . But mant chinese junk apps :(. any other help

Comment: I would root the phone and install a brand new operating system on it. It makes life easier for you in so many ways, and it will solve your problem